# firebase documentation terminology

Tags: firebase, flutter

What do we mean by secondary Firebase App? for instance, it is mentioned here in this documentation - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple projects in your application

> Sometimes you need to access
> different projects using the same APIs - for example, accessing
> multiple database instances. In most cases there is a central Firebase
> application object that manages the configuration for all the Firebase
> APIs. This object is initialized as part of your normal setup.
> However, when you want to access multiple projects from a single
> application, you’ll need a distinct Firebase application object to
> reference each one individually. It’s up to you to initialize these
> other instances.
>
> In both cases, you need to first create a Firebase options object to
> hold the configuration data for the Firebase application

you can [read more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects)

Comment: So basically we can connect multiple project to our application. That means that up to some extent we can bypass the limit set by firebase for using the service for free, as we can connect multiple accounts?

Comment: `we can bypass the limit set by firebase` not the use case, but yes you can connect to multiple firebase projects